# Scheme not divisible

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm try to write a procedure that defines the stream of all integers that are not divisble by either 2, 3, or 5.  This is what I wrote:

```
(define not-d
   (stream-filter (lambda (x) (not (divisible? x (and 2 3 5))))
                 integers))
```

and I test it with:

```
(define (take n s)  ;; list of first n things from stream s
  (if (= n 0)
      '()
      (cons (stream-car s) (take (- n 1) (stream-cdr s)))))
```

However it doesn't work...how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work at all:

```
(not (divisible? x (and 2 3 5)))
```

Try this instead:

```
(and
 (not (divisible? x 2))
 (not (divisible? x 3))
 (not (divisible? x 5)))
```